# My routine to count vowels and consonants is not working

Tags: python, string

I written the code  but the code is not working properly ,what is the error in the code . pls give me suggestion

```
a=input("Enter the string:-")
vowel=0
cons=0
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if (a[i]!=" "):
        if(a[i]=="a" or a[i]=="e" or a[i]=="i" or a[i]=="o" or a[i]=="u"
           or a[i]=="A" or a[i]=="E" or a[i]=="I" or a[i]=="O" or a[i]=="U"):
            vowel=vowel+1

    else:
         cons=cons+1

print("Totle vowels:-",vowel)
print("Totle cons:-",cons)
```

Comment: I think the else branch should be on the second if

Answer (score 0):

The bug was in the indentation, as pointed out by @Diego de Vita. But I would like to suggest a version of your code which is both more readable and more general (think of what happens in your code if you have a comma in the input):

```
from string import punctuation, whitespace

a=input("Enter the string:-")
vowel=0
cons=0
for ch in a.lower():
    if not (ch in punctuation or ch in whitespace):
        if ch in ['aeiou']:
            vowel=vowel+1
        else:
            cons=cons+1

print("Totle vowels:-",vowel)
print("Totle cons:-",cons)
```